# Reverse geocoding + Google Maps API + Django

Tags: django, google-maps

How to make the Google Maps API return the country name and city, and save it in a variable django

Comment: Are you using pymaps? What does saving the values have to do with django? google maps, django, and saving data are all three distinct concepts. Please clarify exactly what you are doing and are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

As your question lacks information, below is the Google auto complete text input. You enter the location and it will return the city, state, country, postcode, latitude, longitude (which it find) which displayed within `li` tags. You can use the approach to store in other variables instead of `li`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qb68p/) is the jsfiddle of it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var geocoder;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
          new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

        var input = document.getElementById('location');
        var options = {
          bounds: defaultBounds,
          types: ['(regions)']
        };

        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); 
            var city;
            var state;
            var country;
            var postcode;
            var latitude;
            var longitude;

            if (place){
                address_components = place.address_components;
                if (address_components){
                    for (index in address_components){
                        component = address_components[index];
                        if (component.types.indexOf('locality') > -1){
                            city = component.long_name;
                        }
                        if (component.types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_1') > -1){
                            state = component.long_name;
                            if (!state){
                                if (component.types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_2') > -1){
                                    state = component.long_name;
                                    if (!state){
                                        if (component.types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_3') > -1){
                                            state = component.long_name;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (component.types.indexOf('country') > -1){
                            country = component.long_name;
                        }
                        if (component.types.indexOf('postal_code') > -1){
                            postcode = component.long_name;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (place.geometry){
                    if (place.geometry.location){
                        latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                        longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (city){
                $('.city').text('City: ' + city);
            }else{$('.city').text('City: ');}
            if (state){
                $('.state').text('State: ' + state);
            }else{$('.state').text('State: ');}
            if (country){
                $('.country').text('Country: ' + country);
            }else{$('.country').text('Country: ');}
            if (postcode){
                $('.postcode').text('Postcode: ' + postcode);
            }else{$('.postcode').text('Postcode: ');}
            if (latitude){
                $('.latitude').text('Latitude: ' + latitude);
            }else{$('.latitude').text('Latitude: ');}
            if (longitude){
                $('.longitude').text('Longitude: ' + longitude);
            }else{$('.longitude').text('Longitude: ');}
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="location" name="location">
<ul>
    <li class="city">City: </li>
    <li class="state">State: </li>
    <li class="country">Country: </li>
    <li class="postcode">Postcode: </li>
    <li class="latitude">Latitude: </li>
    <li class="longitude">Longitude: </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```